# Composite Index from Code

Tags: java, neo4j

How can I create a composite index in Neo4j v3.3.1 using Java 1.8?

I use the following for a single property, `graphDb.schema().indexFor(label).on(indexProperty).create();`.

The docs say:

> NOTE: currently only a single property key per index is supported.

So I'm assuming there is a different API for composite indices?

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't supported programatically. You would have to execute a cypher query to create the index.

EDIT

With regard to the assumption that "anything doable with Cypher is absolutely doable in some form or fashion by the Java API":

Yes and no. On the Java side there is the internal Kernel API, and the public Core API.

Anything doable with Cypher is supported via the Kernel API, however this is not guaranteed to be unchanged between versions, so you would potentially have to spend some more time on maintenance when upgrading. You would also need to authorize the procs using the kernel API in your neo4j.conf. More to the point, this is often not user friendly, and sometimes not very developer friendly. I can try to get more details, but my understanding is this is a fairly complicated thing to do.

The Core API is the recommended API for embedded Neo4j and procedures, and is generally more user friendly, and has more guarantees in terms of changes allowed or restricted with patch/minor/major versions (being a public API), but there are some areas where it doesn't cover all functionality from the kernel API or that's exposed via Cypher. Currently that missing functionality includes node key constraints and composite indexes.

The workaround and recommended approach here is to use `db.execute()` to execute a cypher query with the composite index or node key constraint creation (or dropping). This is also the approach APOC uses in the `apoc.schema.assert()` procedure. See [this snippet of code](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.2/src/main/java/apoc/schema/Schemas.java#L153), looks like something you can reuse yourself.

Comment: That really changes my understanding of the API... I have been assuming for several years that anything doable with Cypher is absolutely doable in some form or fashion by the Java API. Perhaps hard, perhaps tedious, but always exposed...

Comment: Updated my answer. I'm trying to get more details from devs on how this could be done via the kernel API, but the impression I get is "here be dragons". Provided a workaround that may be easier for you.

Comment: I would be interested it in looking at Kernel API options; though documentation seems scarce...